# ternary operator not working for this.state react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

Trying to change my header background color (for a start, eventually i will change more with the style. ) by a click.

however it fails to work .

```
toggleHeader(){
    var newState;
    newState = "headerBig" ? "headerSmall" : "headerBig";
    this.setState({
    toggleHeader: newState
})
```

}

What i'm trying to change is my header className={this.state.toggleHeader}

Am I not doing this right?

console log keeps returning "headerSmall" after it changes once.

**Fixed**

I used this code to fix it... 
added a state of "isHeaderBig" and i am toggling that too. seems like double the work,, but.

`toggleHeader(){
    var newState = (this.state.isHeaderBig ? "headerSmall" : "headerBig");
    this.setState({
      toggleHeader: newState,
      isHeaderBig: !this.state.isHeaderBig
    })
  }`

Comment: you are testing a string, not a variable.

Comment: "headerBig" is truthy...

Comment: Thanks I see my noobish ways now. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
toggleHeader(){
var newState;
newState = this.state.toggleHeader === "headerBig" ? "headerSmall" : "headerBig";
this.setState({
toggleHeader: newState
```

})

this is the right way, "headerBig" is always true

Comment: oh jeez. How did I forget that. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of writing the line with the ternary operator is:

```
newState = newState === "headerBig" ? "headerSmall" : "headerBig";
```

Notice the comparison on the left of `?`.

Otherwise, just `"headerBig"` will always evaluate to `true` and the ternary operator will always return `"headerSmall"`. This is the first problem.

The second one is you have to keep `newState` **outside** the function, or it will loose the state between clicks.

This is a working example:

```js
var newState = "headerBig"; // outside the handler

$("#headertest").on("click", () => {
  newState = newState === "headerBig" ? "headerSmall" : "headerBig"; // with condition
  $("#headertest").text(newState);
});

$("#headertest").text(newState); // initialize
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="headertest"></div>
```

Comment: but he uses `var newState;` any comment on that?

Comment: is this jQuery? so I should instead set newState before the render , then pass it into the function onClick?

Comment: so what I ended up doing was passing "this.state.toggleHeader" into the function and then: 

`  toggleHeader(s){
    s = (s === "headerBig" ? "headerSmall" : "headerBig");
    this.setState({
      toggleHeader: s
    })
  } `

Answer (score 0):

```
newState = "headerBig" ? "headerSmall" : "headerBig";
```

Is basically the same as

```
if ("headerBig") {
    newState = "headerSmall"
} else {
    newState = "headerBig"
}
```

Do you see what the problem is? `"headerBig"` is truthy, so the first case will ways run.

Perhaps you meant something like:

```
newState = oldState === "headerBig" ? "headerSmall" : "headerBig";
```